# how write to file perline python, what wrong in my python script?

Tags: python-3.x

Write to file all lines.

```
f = open('j:/text.txt', 'r')
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
    f1 = open('j:/out.txt', 'a')
    f1.write(''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in line.strip('\n')) + "\n")
    print (''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in line.strip('\n')))
    print (line.strip('\n'))
```

this script normal display at print all info but when i try write to file , its only writes first line and stop.

Comment: You should flush your contents and close the file. Perhaps that fixes your flow

Comment: Yes it was solution i forgot about f1.close()

Answer (score 0):

To write lines in line:

```
writelines(line)
```